# Combining @Entity class of ObjectBox and kotlinx.serialization results in conflict

Tags: android, kotlin, objectbox

I am trying to pass a data class in a Bundle. In order to do this requires that the data class be Serialized. However, this seems to present a problem as soon as you introduce @Serializable annotation combined with the @Entity annotation especially with a data class that has relations.

```
@Entity
@Serializable 
data class BasketItem(
    @Id var id: Long = 0,
    var barcode: String? = null,
    var productName: String? = null,
    var taxTypeID: Int = 0,
    var tax: Int = 0,
    var retailSellingPrice: Int = 0,
    var participatedInRule: Boolean = false,
    var looseItemMeasurement: Int = 0,
    var isAReturn: Boolean = false,
    var addedTimestamp: String? = null,
    var costPrice: Int = 0)
```

I am currently using kotlinx.serialization. Any way I can achieve the serialization of an object box data class ?

Comment: Have you tried Parcelable and Parcelize since these can also go in a Bundle? If that doesn't work, I would actually declare two separate classes, one which is data layer and one which is used by Activity/Fragment

Comment: I agree. Also, I recommend against passing a full entity. Just pass its id and then get it wherever needed. Recommended reading: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the instance that you are using your data class between two languages i.e Java and Kotlin it seems that if you want to serialize a data class you should import the java version of serializable. I was trying to pass the data in data class to pass it to a Java class, I was using Kotlin serialization and it did not seem to work with the java codebase. At the end of it all the solution was to import the following :

import java.io.Serializable

and extend the data class

```
@Entity
data class BasketItem(
    @Id var id: Long = 0,
    var barcode: String? = null,
    var productName: String? = null,
    var taxTypeID: Int = 0,
    var tax: Int = 0,
    var retailSellingPrice: Int = 0,
    var participatedInRule: Boolean = false,
    var looseItemMeasurement: Int = 0,
    var isAReturn: Boolean = false,
    var addedTimestamp: String? = null,
    var costPrice: Int = 0,
) : Serializable
```

This seems to do the trick.